# Using Mapkit offline

Tags: ios, mapkit, offline

I would like to use the Mapkit framework in my app offline, so the user does not have to use roaming to download the tiles. I have seen other maps using google maps and have the tiles in the app without having to download them first.

How could this be done? Could the cached tiles in the cached.db saved somewhere in the project so they are there by default?
Would I need to create an overlay?

I have seen a number of similar questions, but I am still thinking there might be an answer somewhere out there. Is it really disallowed by Google to use their map images offline?

I know that I could use mapbox, but I am also sure the examples I have seen are not using mapbox.

A thread among many that I have searched:
[Offline MapKit solution for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524317/offline-mapkit-solution-for-ios)

Many thanks!
Andras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible on iOS, there´s neither an API for caching nor is it allowing in the Terms of Usage. As you already stated the only way to allow offline mapping is by using other Map frameworks like Mapbox. MKMapView however does cache a few tiles as long as you loaded them while you had internet connection, you just don't have any control over how many tiles get cached or how long they get cached.

Comment: thanks for your response, I came to the same conclusion. will have to try mapbox then!

Answer (score 0):

you can use overlay technique.Just download one geojson file and fetch data from that which contains coordinates.Plot those coordinates by using overlay.
This method will show your overlay as map in offline mode.