# Create an Offline Map (Save Map to iPhone)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit, offline

I am looking at creating a travel app.  The app would focus on a specific area in the countryside where there is limited internet connection and allow the user to see their location.

So I imagine the map would be saved in the app at all times and then I would use GPS to see my location (if I am in the area of the saved map).

I understand how the mapkit works with an internet connection but I'm not sure on how to make this available offline.

Can someone point me in the right direction of understanding how a saved/offline map would work please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline MapKit solution for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524317/offline-mapkit-solution-for-ios)

Comment: Most of the offline map questions I have found are very old.  That one was asked in 2012

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you still can't do it with MapKit, here is a newer post from 2017 using MapTiler:

https://playcode.org/custom-map-using-maptiler/

Sorry, can't comment, not enough reputation.